# chainlit test failed

Tags: python, chatbot, windows, pip

I am using windows OS. I created a folder named ABC under C.  In command prompt, I typed cd C:\ABC and then typed the following commands:

```
pip install huggingface_hub 
pip install transformers
pip install langchain
pip install chainlit
```

The above commands completed with success (or at least it seems so.) Then I typed

```
 chainlit hello
```

to test the installation. I get the error 'chainlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I added the path C:\ABC to "PATH" my environment variables, both for system and user. I still face the same problem. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, chainlit for me got installed into the python scripts directory C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\chainlit.exe where XYZ is your username.

so you want to check that this is in your path. You can also run 'where chainlit' from a cmd line, but this will only search your path, so it will also fail if chainlit is installed somewhere that isn't in your path.